# How to prove whether this function is continuous or not?

Tags: functions, continuity

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2, \mbox{  } (\forall) \mbox{ } x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
-2, \mbox{  } (\forall) \mbox{ } x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$

Usually piece wise functions can be checked for continuity by taking limit at the end points of the intervals. But, how to do this problem? Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 8):

The image of an interval by a continuous function is an interval. By the density of $\Bbb Q$, the image of any interval is $\{-2,2\}$.

Answer (score 5):

It is not continuous.

Hint:

For any $x \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$, there exists $\{x_n: x_n \in \Bbb Q\}$ converges $x$, then $f(x_n)=2 \not= -2=f(x)$.

Answer (score 5):

$f(x)$ continuous at $a$ means for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$

Taking the negation of the definition

$f(x)$ is not continuous at $a$ means there exist a $\epsilon>0$, for all $\delta>0$ we have $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(a)|\geq \epsilon$

Back to your question, take $\epsilon=4$ and reread the definition of $f$ not continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Take a sequence of rationals(irrationals) converging to an irrational(rational). The function is discontinuous everywhere.